# Roads vs The roads, At these times vs In these times

Tags: prepositions, articles

Here's a sentence written in my textbook.

> The problem isn't just confined to **roads**, but also the subway systems that are packed with commuters in the morning or evening peak hours. It is next to impossible to move in the subway cars **at these times**.

1. In this sentence, roads is simply referring to unspecific roads. But, if I rephrase it as '**the roads**', it is more likely to refer to the class of objects called road. So, no matter which one I use, there's no big difference. I'd like to know the difference between 'roads' and 'the roads'.
2. I know that depending on what I want to use, I can choose the word between 'at' and 'in' to tell time phrases. At the end of the sentence, if I want to use 'in' not 'at', how can I rephrase it? **'In these times'** is just okay?
   I'd like to know the difference between 'at' and 'in'.

Answer (score 4):

1) *roads* as used here is a mass noun (roads in general cause some problem). So no article is used.

2) When you say:

> **at these times**

it is referring to specific time based occasions. So you would use *at*. Same as:

> Sometimes the train is late. **At these times**...
>   **At** the end of the class...

This applies to the example you provided.

As for:

> In these times

Here *in* is like *during*, so it would be referring to a period of time. For example:

> Life was difficult during the Great Depression. **In those times**, there were many people who were unemployed.

Answer (score 1):

@user3169's answer is correct.  However, I'll just add…

The use of a definite article before *roads* is optional, and there is only a subtle distinction, if any, if it is included.  It is also possible to insert *the* there, like this:

> Seoul suffers huge economic losses due to inadequate transportation infrastructure.  The problem isn't just confined to the roads, but also the subway systems that are packed with commuters in the morning or evening peak hours.

In that context, "the roads" refers to the roads of Seoul.

Comment: This is true. Though the author chose to leave the article out, there's no harm (or change of meaning) when leaving it in.